# Is it possible to send TCP packet to UDP-only server?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, udp

I have a UDP server, but I have no UDP capability on client side. Is there a way to send packet via TCP so that UDP server can receive it normally? UDP server cannot be transformed into TCP server.

Reason for wanting to do this is that I'm using a SOCKS5 proxy that does not support UDP associate capability, but I have to use that proxy.

Answer (score 1):

No. The UDP server cannot complete the 3-way handshake required for TCP. If you have IP-raw sockets, it is actually easier to implement UDP on top. However it seems extremely unlikely that you don't have a UDP-stack.

When you talk about "no UDP capability" do you mean the client has no UDP-stack, or is he just behind some firewall that blocks UDP? In the latter case use a proxy.

Comment: I'm using a SOCKS5 proxy that does not support UDP associate capability, but I have to use it

Comment: I don't think you can in that case (https://superuser.com/questions/1191935/udp-traffic-through-socks). Unless you can connect to a server behind the proxy, on which you run an ALG(application layer gateway), which reads the TCP-stream, creates UDP-messages from it, then repackages the response into TCP. If you are looking for ways to establish connections through proxies/firewalls RFC 5245 (Interactive Connection Establishment) has a few nice tricks which are more or less applicable depending on your situation. Mostly talks about NAT, but applies to firewalls equally in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

No, UDP server will not going to accept TCP packets at all (it's a different protocol, so network stack will never propagate those to the application).

If you have to use SOCKS5 proxy, the only way to connect to the said server is by using another proxy-like application, which will stand beyond SOCKS5, accept TCP connections (initiated by app behind SOCKS5 proxy) and retransmit data as UDP.

Comment: It won't simply ignore them. TCP will send RST packets if there is no such connection.

Comment: @EJP true, I meant to say, ignore from the perspective of the upstream UDP app. I think I'd better clarify